# What is .Net Rc1

Tags: .net

Does .Net Rc1/Rc2 is a separate installation from .Net extended and client profile. 
Can some explain the difference in the application, MVC or RC1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC stands for Model View Controller and is a design framework for web applications. There are two parts, the developer framework and the supporting tools that let you run the web application on your server.

Jon Galloway wrote a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/07/13/server-installation-options-for-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) about the various ways you can install the server side components:

> So if you have desktop access to the server, probably the best option is to [install ASP.NET MVC 2 via WebPI.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=185037)

As barryj states RC stands for Release Candidate so this will be a version that you use to test that your applications will work with the full version of what ever framework/operating system you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

RC1/RC2 in software terms refers to Release Candidate 1, Release Candidate 2. It's the name given to a software package by the publisher just prior to release, typically after beta releases. It's expected that these will be very close to the final released package. But Release Candidates are not final versions. After Release Candidate, the final release is often referred to as Golden Master or GM.

Comment: we have installed .Net 2.0/3.5 and 4.0 in our servers. But one of our customers asking for .Net Rc2 which I have no idea (before asking the question). Does these installations has anything to do with .Net RC2